Is there a simple and efficient way of checking the exact frame a boolean value changes from true to false or vice versa, then calling a function?
This is my first time posting here so apologies if I'm not providing enough details for y'all. I feel as if I'm going insane trying to do something I thought would be so simple and straightforward! For context, I am currently writing behavior states for an enemy guard in a stealth game project I have been working on. Basic things like patrolling, investigating, combat, and searching. I am trying to find out the exact frame the player breaks line of sight from the enemy. I will then, at that same frame, grab the players position and store it so the enemy can search around that area.
I am not sure if my problem is a lack of knowledge of C# or I need a break or something, probably a combination of both, but regardless I feel as if there should already be a system for that built into Unity already? No?
I need a break right now but I'll be on the lookout for answers, and I'm ready to offer my code for help if that would be any use.
Thanks!
(Edit): Here is my enemy vision code:
// Obstruction raycast check
    if (Physics.Raycast(headObj.position, (player.transform.position - headObj.position).normalized, Vector3.Distance(headObj.position, player.transform.position), obstructionLayer) == false)
    {
        if (playerInVisionCone)
        {
            if(awareness < awarenessCombatThreshold)
            {
                awareness += Time.deltaTime * distanceAwarenessMultiplier;
            }
            
        }
        // Enemy gains less awareness when looking through peripheral vision
        // Enemy can't see player if they are crouching or sliding inside the peripheral vision cone
        else if (playerInPVisionCone && !playerInVisionCone && !isCrouched && !isSliding)
        {
            if (awareness < awarenessCombatThreshold)
            {
                awareness += Time.deltaTime * pVisionAwarenessMultiplier * distanceAwarenessMultiplier;
            }
        }
        // Player is not in vision cone of enemy
        else if (!playerInPVisionCone && !playerInVisionCone)
        {
            if(awareness > 0)
            {
                awareness -= Time.deltaTime * awarenessCooldownMultiplier;
                
            }
        }
    }
    // Player is behind a wall
    else
    {
        if(awareness > 0)
        {
            awareness -= Time.deltaTime * awarenessCooldownMultiplier;
        }
    }


Post your code. Otherwise we can't help you.

YOU are drawing all of this stuff, right?  Can't you figure the line of sight for every frame you draw?

@TimRoberts Yes, but I need the exact frame the boolean value changes. In this case, once line of sight is broken, a boolean will be true for exactly one frame, as to only execute the search function one time. Then on the next frame, even if there is still no line of sight to the player, the boolean must be false. The Vector3 "lastKnownPos" should be the position of the player on the same frame that line of sight is broken. If the function runs every frame, the enemy will grab the players position every frame, thus leading to the enemy essentially having "wall hacks". If that makes sense

But you can check this condition for every frame you draw, right?  It's all under your control.

@TimRoberts Yeah

Did you consider using a property instead of a field? Otherwise also what hinders you from using an event instead of poll checking a field?


Is there a simple and efficient way of checking the exact frame a boolean value changes from true to false or vice versa, then calling a function?


The classic way of doing this is to store your value to a boolean field and then compare the new value to the old value in the next frame:
bool _oldValue;

void Update() {
    bool newValue = your calculations;
    if (newValue != _oldValue) {
        _oldValue = newValue;
        YourFunction();
    }
}

void YourFunction() { }

This is the right way to do it when all your logic is in a single class. In case you have a lot of such variables at some point and it becomes a mess, you should consider refactoring your code into multiple classes.




You can use a property:
bool _value;
bool Value {
    set {
        if(_value == value)
           return;

        _value = value;
        YourFunction();
    }
}

void YourFunction() { }

void Update() {
    Value = your calculations;
}

This approach seems neat at the first glance but the issue here is that programmers usually don't expect side effects from properties. Calling a function that changes something else is a side effect. You can still use this approach for as long as the property is not exposed as public. But in a real project where multiple programmers are working together consider not doing this.




It is also possible to encapsualte the value in a class:
public class Value {
   bool _value;
   public bool HasChanged { get; private set; }
   public Value(bool value = false) => _value = value;
   public void Update(bool newValue) {
       IsChanged = newValue != _value;
       _value = newValue;
   }
}

but as you can see below, this doesn't offer a lot of benefits code-wise by itself:
Value _myValue = new();

void Update() {
    bool newValue = your calculations;
    _myValue.Update(newValue);
    if (_myValue.IsChanged) {
        YourFunction();
    }
}

In other words, introducing such a general-purpose class for just storing and checking a variable makes no sense. It is the same number of lines of code, it doesn't add clarity etc.




When there are multiple classes in your code, you can start using events. This is also the right way to do when some of the APIs expose events for you. Here's the implementation of a plain C# event:
public class Value {
    bool _value;
    public event Action ValueChanged;
    public Value(bool value = false) => _value = value;
    public void Update(bool newValue) {
        if (newValue == _value)
            return;

        _value = newValue;
        ValueChanged?.Invoke();

    }
}

And then you use it like this:
Value _myValue = new();
void OnEnable() => _myValue.ValueChanged += YourFunction;
void OnDisable() => _myValue.ValueChanged -= YourFunction;
void YourFunction() { }

void Update() {
    bool newValue = your calculations;
    _myValue.Update(newValue);
}

This code already screams that your calculations part should go to the Update of the Value class, as it is now clear that this class is the one making decisions. I will not go into depths of refactoring here, but class extraction is a common tool of it. Also, don't forget to rename classes according to their purpose.
Events also allow parameters:
public class Value {
    bool _value;
    public event Action<bool> ValueChanged;
    public Value(bool value = false) => _value = value;
    public void Update(bool newValue) {
        if (newValue == _value)
            return;

        _value = newValue;
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(_value);
    }
}

Value _myValue = new();
void OnEnable() => _myValue.ValueChanged += YourFunction;
void OnDisable() => _myValue.ValueChanged -= YourFunction;
void YourFunction(bool newValue) { }

void Update() {
    bool newValue = your calculations;
    _myValue.Update(newValue);
}

C# events also work with MonoBehaviour's:
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    public event Action HasHappened;
}

public class Bar : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] Foo _foo;

    void OnEnable() => _foo.HasHappened += OnHappened;
    void OnDisable() => _foo.HasHappened -= OnHappened;

    void OnHappened() { }
}

So you can make the Value class a MonoBehaviour instead of sending all the parameters to its Update. Or you can use events to communicate between your Enemy and Player class. A common implementation is when one class calls the methods of the other directly and subscribes to its events to hear back from it.
Also, C# events are not exposed to the Inspector. For that you would want to use Unity Events




Finally, there are more advanced tools, like signals (often bundled with Dependency Injection frameworks, like Zenject) or reactive extensions, e.g. UniRx or R3. These tools implement different approaches of communication between classes.


For as long as you operate within a single class, go with the field or property approach. As soon as multiple classes are involved, start looking into events and other tools.

Oh wow, this very well may have saved my project. Thanks a lot man! I used the first example in my project and it instantly fixed all of my issues. I was also able to change it a little to it to fit my needs better, and it works flawlessly. I will be keeping these 2 methods in my repertoire, and I plan on taking a couple hours or so into studying more about events. I have seen them used online before, but have never delved into them myself. Have a blessed one dude!
